# How to catch the error "InputMismatchException" in Java and print a personalized message , without using try and catch?

Tags: java, regex

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
    int source_radix = sc.nextInt();
    String sr = source_radix+"";
    if (!Pattern.matches("[0-9]+",sr) || source_radix <1 || source_radix >36)
    {
        System.out.print("error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

**I want to print "error" when the input is not an integer.**

Comment: It is already throwing an exception when you enter not an int, so what's the problem?

Comment: [`Scanner#nextInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt--) will throw "`InputMismatchException` - if the next token does not match the Integer regular expression, or is out of range". That's what you are getting right now.

Comment: I want to catch the error and Print the error message "ERROR".

Comment: Then do exactly what you said, use `try` and `catch` to catch the exception.

Comment: I need to do it without using try and catch.

Comment: Btw. it is really bad practice to silence an exception like that. When you catch an exception you should either handle it properly, rethrow a new exception while appending the original one or at least logging the stacktrace.

Comment: Then you should read the whole line (with `nextLine`), validate it and handle accordingly.

Comment: @Polly if you are not supposed to work with exceptions (try / catch) here, then you should get the user input as a `String` via `nextLine()` instead of `nextInt()`, then check (via your regex for example) if it is a valid integer and can be parsed, and then use `Integer.parseInt(str)` to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to prevent that exception being thrown from `nextInt()` is to call `hasNextInt()` first.  In your specific example, we could do this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int radix = 0;
if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
    radix = sc.nextInt();
}
if (radix < 1 || radix > 36) {
    System.out.print("error");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

You could modify that to print different error messages to distinguish the cases where the user didn't enter a valid integer, and where they entered a integer that was outside of the required range.

In some situations, it may be necessary to call `sc.nextLine()` to discard something that isn't a valid number, or anything on the line *after* the number.   (But it isn't necessary if the app is going to terminate on getting bad input.)

Finally, it is often a bad idea to call `System.exit(0)`.  If this is in your `main` method, `return` will work just as well.  If it is not in `main`, then it probably should not be this code's responsibility to "pull the plug" on the application.  But ... it is not clear cut.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if input is number of range from 1 to 36 by only using Regex:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String sr  = sc.nextLine();

if (!Pattern.matches("[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[0-6]", sr)) {
    System.out.print("error");
    System.exit(0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try this `Java` code:

```sh
   Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
   String sr = sc.next(); // read a string

   // check if we have all digits in input
   boolean match = Pattern.matches("[0-9]+", sr);

   // if yes then convert to int and do comparison
   if (match) {
       int source_radix = Integer.parseInt(sr);
       if (source_radix <1 || source_radix >36) match = false;
   }

   // handle error if match is false
   if (!match) {
       System.out.print("error");
       System.exit(0);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something this:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
while(sc.hasNext()) {
    String str =sc.nextLine();
    if (!Pattern.matches("[0-9]+",str) ||( Pattern.matches("[0-9]+",str) &&     Integer.parseInt(str)) <1 )|| ( Pattern.matches("[0-9]+",str) && Integer.parseInt(str)) <1 ) >36) {
        System.out.print("error");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe this will help? [Markdown Editing Help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)